# how can i start jar file with out STS

Tags: spring-boot

I try to do `java -jar jarname.jar` but I get an error.

However if I start the project on STS I don't get the error from before.

I don't understand why it's not working and why STS works and just jar doesn't work either.

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/YSJ/Desktop/SJ/spring%20pj/scheduledPj/target/scheduledPj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/YSJ/Desktop/SJ/spring%20pj/scheduledPj/target/scheduledPj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.28.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.0.RELEASE)

2019-10-31 16:22:19.283  INFO 3952 --- [           main] com.scheduledPj.ScheduledPjApplication   : Starting ScheduledPjApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on KC20114 with PID 3952 (C:\Users\YSJ\Desktop\SJ\spring pj\scheduledPj\target\scheduledPj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by YSJ in C:\Users\YSJ\Desktop\SJ\spring pj\scheduledPj\target)
2019-10-31 16:22:19.289  INFO 3952 --- [           main] com.scheduledPj.ScheduledPjApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-31 16:22:20.284  WARN 3952 --- [           main] o.m.s.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner      : No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.dao]' package. Please check your configuration.
2019-10-31 16:22:20.465  WARN 3952 --- [           main] o.m.s.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner      : No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.scheduledPj]' package. Please check your configuration.
2019-10-31 16:22:22.790  INFO 3952 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-10-31 16:22:22.801  INFO 3952 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-10-31 16:22:22.801  INFO 3952 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2019-10-31 16:22:22.899  INFO 3952 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-10-31 16:22:22.900  INFO 3952 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3493 ms
2019-10-31 16:22:23.029  WARN 3952 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sqlSession'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2019-10-31 16:22:23.035  INFO 3952 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-10-31 16:22:23.105  INFO 3952 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-31 16:22:23.108 ERROR 3952 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dependencies:<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <version>1.4.199</version>
</dependency>

Properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: i add mssql-jdbc dependencies and add db url in apllication.yml so it's work on STS but not java -jar

Comment: can you share the properties yaml with config <ofcos not credentials>

Comment: spring:
  datasource:
     url: jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:8443;databasename=BACKUP

Comment: driver-class-name: net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy

Comment: username: 1234
    password: 1234

Comment: that's it no more else

Answer (score 0):

Did you did any specific config or settings?

Comment: just make new spring start project and make Application.yml

Comment: It seems, it does not recognize the url for database, please check the syntax or give the h2 in memory db properly. As from error, it cannot initialize the datasource, error must be from that space.

Comment: [link]https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-spring-boot-for-microsoft-sql-server[/link]

please check for this one

Comment: the link : We can't find the page you're looking for.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-spring-boot-for-microsoft-sql-server

should work now

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in STS you have configured the parameter `url` in some way. If you start the application with `java -jar` you also have to provide the parameter. for example: `java -jar myspringbootapp.jar --url=jdbc:blabla`

Comment: what does url's mean?

Comment: Did you read the message of your exception? `Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.` You use an attribute called `url` in your application. So you have to specify it in someway. Spring boot uses a default H2 database only in test environment. In any other environment you have to specify your datasource.